# Can a Tampermonkey userscript save data into a synced storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I have a userscript for Google Chrome's Tampermonkey. Currently, it uses HTML5 local storage to save its data but I would like this data to be synchronized across all computers the signed-on user uses.

The `GM_setValue` function only saves data to the local disk, and that data is not synced to other computers.

I don't need compatibility with Firefox.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How/Where to store data in a Chrome Tampermonkey script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730216/how-where-to-store-data-in-a-chrome-tampermonkey-script)

Comment: That question only concerns saving locally, not to all computers the Chrome user uses.

Comment: Are you sure `GM_setValue` doesn't sync? If so, you should make a note of why this does not work in the question.

Comment: For my experience Tampermonkey doesn't sync scripts either

Comment: It is possible to sync scripts if you enable it in Tampermonkey's advanced options.

Comment: Not possible at the moment - [there's an issue open](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/825) in the extension's repo, however.